# Connection pool reset

Tags: java, oracle11g, connection, connection-pooling

I am running a job- basically it opens connection, executes SP, then returns connection to the pool. If I run the job immediately again, it will get that same connection from the pool, and will run fine. but if I run the job again after a certain amount of time(about an hour or so), it gets that same connection then gets a connection reset error upon executing the SP. Here is the exception I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:987)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1170)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doScrollExecuteCommon(OracleStatement.java:4043)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.doScrollPstmtExecuteUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10826)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3337)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4394)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but most database disconnect if the connection is idle for too long. If you want to make it wait longer, you will have to chage your database settings. For that, please consult the Oracle database manual.

Comment: I'd guess that you have a network component-- a firewall most likely-- that is configured to terminate connections that have been open or idle too log.  If so, the firewall administrator would need to add an exception.  It could also be that the network isn't stable enough to keep connections open indefinitely.